memory_usage from memory_profiler calling the function multiple times
Ive wrote a decorator to run memory_usage and get the peak to logging, however it sometimes calls the function multiple times.
def profile_memory(func):
    @functools.wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        logging.info(f"Starting {func.__name__}")
        mem_usage = memory_usage((func,args,kwargs), interval=1)
        logging.info(f"Max memory usage is {round(max(mem_usage),2)} mb for {func.__name__}")

    return wrapper

I dont really know what to try, it does it for multiple function in my package
